# Where to find the SWI-Prolog Library Source Code

Tags: prolog, porting, swi-prolog, xsb

I am trying to port some of the libraries from SWI-Prolog to XSB-Prolog.
Where can I find the source code of these libraries? Lets say that I want to port the `url` library. Where can I find the Prolog source code for the same. I already took a look at the following link:
http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=summary-lib-url

Answer (score 3):

It is on github .. https://github.com/SWI-Prolog

https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/master/library/url.pl

blah blah blah blah to meet character limit of answers